# postgres cube euclidean distance query performance issues

Tags: postgresql, performance, cube

I have a postgres database containing a table of documents with word embeddings of 100 dimensions and using it to find similar documents.

```
CREATE TABLE documents(
   id bigint,
   title text,
   body text,
   vector double[],
   PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

I have installed the `cube` extension and using it to sort documents by similarity from a selected document thus (as explained [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/163207/quick-nearest-neighbor-search-in-the-150-dimensional-space)):

```
SELECT id,title,body FROM documents ORDER BY cube(documents.vector) 
 <-> '(0.0990813672542572021,.. 0.0537704713642597198)'::cube  LIMIT 10;
```

I have the index setup here:
`CREATE INDEX ix_vect ON documents USING gist (cube(vector));`

I am getting results as expected, but the query time is inordinately long ~30-45 second for a table size of ~2 Million rows. How can I improve performance to bring it down to acceptable levels i.e. <1 sec on millions of rows?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to use CUBE by [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/cube.html):

```
SELECT c FROM test ORDER BY c <-> cube(array[0.5,0.5,0.5]) LIMIT 1;
```